# Specify project ruby version independent of whether I use `rvm` or `rbenv`?

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv

Not wanting to commit to e.g. `.rvmrc` for specifying the ruby version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top-level directory of your project, create a file named `.ruby-version` containing only the version of ruby you want to use, e.g.

```
2.1.0
```

You can sometimes also specify `system` (known example: MacOS).

Answer (score 1):

If your project is using a Gemfile you can set it [there](http://bundler.io/gemfile_ruby.html) too:

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

This is of course 'per project' and not global. Heroku uses it that way.

Comment: Do you know if `rvm` and/or `rbenv` pick up the ruby version from the `Gemfile`?